# CSS Background-Attachment: Fixed

Tags: css, background, background-image

When I use background-attachment: fixed; in firefox the top part of the page has a weird border

Example image: http://www.socialaddicts.net/wtf.png

It works on another page and in other browsers, just not this page // browser.

Comment: I see a border atop that image in Chrome and IE, looking at the specific image you're linking. I think it's the image, not the browser.

Comment: the border only shows around the top and left and right parts of the top bar... for example go to http://www.socialaddicts.net/index.php?TEST=1

Comment: I pulled your site up in Firefox, IE and Chrome..  no border.  My guess is that you have a local caching issue.. or you've fixed it by now.

Answer (score 1):

The image has a top border embedded in it.

The only reasons I can think of that it doesn't appear on another page is that your css is positioning the border part of the image off screen.

If I were you, I'd take the border out of the image.

Comment: i dont see a border in the image :/

Comment: it doesnt matter if i even make the background image size 50px 50px its still there... if i remove the background-attachment its gone

Comment: @theshittmasta: The image you linked to has a border embedded in it.  If that isn't the image you are using the please update your question to include 1) the code used for the webpage and the link to the real image.

Comment: that image was a screen shot of what was happening

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>body {background-image:url('untitled.JPG'); background-attachment: fixed; background-repeat: no-repeat;" }</style>
```

Comment: One out of context suggestion.. Your 1.png file is of 2.5MB. It takes too much time to load.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add this:

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
```

But well, it's an image, not a webpage so you can't i guess.